# Magento Category Link 404

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have 2 root categories where one is to be shown at the top navigation bar and another at the product pages.

- Root Category 1
- Root Category 2

I set "Root Category 1" as the "Base Category" and it works fine. But when I try to link to the second category I always get a bad formed URL and a following 404 page.

```
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
   $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
   echo $_categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($_cat);
endforeach;
```

And I get following results `http://example.com/catalog/category/view/s/url-key/id/11/`.

Any ideas on how to fix this or a better aproach?

Comment: tried running url reindex?

Comment: Yes, reindexed all data but not cigar!

Comment: A store should have only 1 root category, you probably are not using the best method here. Move your Root2 in Root1 and set the parameter 'include_in_navigation' to false. Then your category will exist in the current store and you'll be able to perform code with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Created two root categories and wanted to link to newly created root category in static block using widget. No matter what code I put it was not working, then deleted the new root category and created new sub category and problem SOLVED.